# Why and when im gonna use the parameter "code" of the os.exit() function in Lua

Tags: parameters, lua, operating-system, exit

In the Lua documentation, they say that the `code` parameter in `os.exit([code])` returns a value other than 0 when exiting the script, like, if I run the following line:

```lua
os.exit(7)
```

it will produce the following output:

```lua
>Exit code: 7
```

My question is **why and when would it be useful to change the exit value of the script? like, when and where would I work with this exit code "7"?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value is returned to the process that ran the Lua interpreter; the C language has the same facility.

Typically, `0` is returned on the successful execution of a script, and a nonzero value is returned when there is some kind of error. If a Lua script were called from another script, an error code could guide the calling script in handling the error.

In Bash, you can inspect the returned value by checking the `$?` shell variable:

```
$ lua -e "os.exit(7)"
$ echo $?
7
```

If you call a Lua script from another Lua script using [`os.execute`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.execute), the exit code is the third of three returned values:

`handy_script`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

io.write(string.format("Doing something important...\n"))
os.exit(7)
```

`main_script`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

b, s, n = os.execute("./handy_script")
io.write(string.format("handy_script returned %s, %s: %d\n", tostring(b), s, n))
```

```
$  ./main_script
Doing something important...
handy_script returned nil, exit: 7
```

The first value returned by `os.execute` is the boolean `true` if the command was successfully executed, `fail` otherwise (as of Lua 5.4, `fail` is still equivalent to `nil`). The second value returned is the string `"exit"` if the command terminated normally, or `"signal"` if it was terminated by a signal. The third value returned is the exit code from the call to `os.exit()`, here `7`.